# How to display 2 blocks in one view

Tags: views, blocks

I am using quick tabs, but I want to display 2 blocks under each tab, been told I should use attachments but I don't get.

How can I achieve this?

[image]

So each tab displays 2 blocks when clicked like in the sketch.

Comment: Are your blocks created using Views?

Comment: Hi, i just created the blocks separately under blocks, they are plain simple blocks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using the module [Block Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/blockgroup). You can group multiple blocks into a single block using this module.